# Not able to figure out the query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have created a table to cater to some customer requirements, and have to write a query on the data to be stored in the table. I am not able to figure out an optimal way to write my query.

My table is structured like:

```
c1   c2_lower_limit   c2_upper_limit   c3_lower_limit   c3_upper_limit   rate   operator
1    0                10000            0                20000            10     AND
1    10000            50000            20000            30000            20     OR
1    50000            NULL             30000            NULL             30     OR 
2    0                10000            0                20000            10     AND
2    10000            50000            20000            30000            20     OR
2    50000            NULL             30000            NULL             30     OR
```

The user specifies a value of `C1` and then values for `C2` and `C3` (simply one value for c2 and one for c3). Let's say that I have to return the rate column as an output. The last column in the table structure is `OPERATOR`, which tells me whether the `C2` and `C3` values should be `AND` or `OR`ed.

I am facing problem in determining the opearator to be used. A user can select any value at her discretion for lower and upper limits. I tried basing my operator selection only on one group - let's say `C2`, but then that is not right, as I need to evaluate all variabels input by the user to get the correct operator.

Let's say that a user enters a value of `0` for c2 and enters a value of `25000` for c3 for `c1 = 1`. Since the values of c3 correspond to the entry with opeartor value of `OR`, I should `OR` the c2 and c3 limit values. In short, if a record with `OR` operator is found, I have to `OR` the c2 and c3 groups.

You can check SQLFiddle for table structure http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f9bf6/11

Comment: And where is your query in sub-optimal form?

Comment: Hi @GolezTrol, I missed posting my query in SQLFiddle window. I have posted it now. I was incorrect o say it was `not optimal`, it was actually not even returning the correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution could be to add a condition on the `operator` field.

Using the `:` notation to signify passed parameters:

```
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  c1 = :c1 
AND    ((operator = 'AND' 
         AND
         (:c2 BETWEEN c2_lower_limit AND c2_upper_limit OR
          (:c2 >= c2_lower_limit AND c2_upper_limit IS NULL) OR
          (c2_lower_limit IS NULL AND :c2 < c2_upper_limit) 
         AND
         (:c3 BETWEEN c3_lower_limit AND c3_upper_limit OR
          (:c3 >= c3_lower_limit AND c3_upper_limit IS NULL) OR
          (c3_lower_limit IS NULL AND :c3 < c3_upper_limit) 
        )
       OR
        (operator = 'OR' 
         AND
         (:c2 BETWEEN c2_lower_limit AND c2_upper_limit OR
          (:c2 >= c2_lower_limit AND c2_upper_limit IS NULL) OR
          (c2_lower_limit IS NULL AND :c2 < c2_upper_limit) 
         OR
         (:c3 BETWEEN c3_lower_limit AND c3_upper_limit OR
          (:c3 >= c3_lower_limit AND c3_upper_limit IS NULL) OR
          (c3_lower_limit IS NULL AND :c3 < c3_upper_limit) 
        )
       )
```

**EDIT:**
Note that there's a lot of code duplicity handling `null`s with a `between` operation. If you can alter the database, I'd add a helper function that does this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION null_safe_between 
(eval NUMBER, lower NUMBER, upper NUMBER) 
RETURN BOOLEAN
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    RETURN eval BETWEEN lower_limit AND upper_limit OR
           (eval >= lower_limit AND upper_limit IS NULL) OR
           (lower_limit IS NULL AND eval < upper_limit);
END;
```